# Regex with PHP - Can't add preg_grep indexes to file

Tags: php, regex, arrays, csv, fatal-error

So, I need to make a script that reads a .csv file, find name: xxxxx with regex, and add the regex results to a txt file.

My Php Script:

```
<?PHP
$array=array();
$file_handle = fopen("CONTACTOS.CSV", "r");
$fp=fopen("teste.txt", "w");
$pattern = '/Nome.+\s+/';
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $i=0;
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $iend=count($line_of_text);
            while($i<=$iend){
                    if (isset($line_of_text[$i])){
                            //$array[]=$line_of_text[$i];
                            array_push($array, $line_of_text[$i]);
                            //fputs($fp, $line_of_text[$i]);
                            //echo($array[$i] . "\n");
                            $i++;
                    }
                    else{
                            $i++;
                        }
            }
}
//print_r($array);
$fl_array = preg_grep("/Nome.+\s+/", $array);
print_r($fl_array);
// ________________________________________
$e=1;
end($fl_array);
$flend=key($fl_array);
reset($fl_array);
$arrayF = array_values($fl_array);
while($e<=$flend){
    if (array_key_exists($e, $arrayF) == true) { 
            //print_r($e . "\n");
            puts($fp, $arrayF[$e]);
            $e++;
        }
    else{
        $e++;
        }
    }
// ________________________________________
//print_r($fl_array);
$fp = fopen('CONTACTOS_NOVO.csv', 'w');
       //fputcsv($fp, $array);
fclose($fp);
fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

Part of CSV File:

```
De: bpsnun@m2g-24-59.spvservers.net [mailto:bpsnun@m2g-24-59.spvservers.net] Em nome de Site - BPS Finance
Enviada: quinta-feira, 18 de Março de 2010 10:57
Para: form@bpsfinance.com
Assunto: Formulário - BPS Finance



Formulário nº: 002136

Data: 18/03/2010 - 11:47:58

Faça JÁ o seu Pedido



Montante Pretendido   



Montante de Crédito Pretendido*:   4000 €

1.  O Preenchimento desta proposta não obriga o cliente à sua aceitação.
2.  Caso algum dos proponentes e/ou seus cônjuges tiverem Incidentes Bancários, a proposta será imediatamente RECUSADA.
3.  Não existem quaisquer custos associados à emissão da Pré-Aprovação.
4.  PRAZO: De 12 a 96 meses. Apresentaremos todas as prestações possíveis para o seu crédito. E você Escolhe!

1º Titular   



Nome*:   MARIA JOAO MOTA
```

I want to save in my $fp .txt file only the `Nome*:     XXXX XXXXXXX XXXX`

What is the problems with my code? The error I'm getting with this code is:

```
Fatal Error: Call to undefined function puts() in C:\XXX\teste.php on line 35
```

Can you help me remade the code to make it work?

**UPDATE!**
Ok no errors now, but the preg_grep isnt wornking, my txt have the same content as the .csv file, and not only the nome*: How can i make my preg_grep work?

Comment: Well your question also answers it, You are using puts function which is not part of atleast php Core. Or you have define your own function or just fputs become puts

Comment: Ok no errors now, but the preg_grep isnt wornking, my txt have the same content as the .csv file, and not only the nome*: How can i make my preg_grep work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
while($e<=$flend){
    if (array_key_exists($e, $arrayF) == true) {
```

you are checking array keys starting from `$e=1;` but the found `Nome` line is stored in `$arrayF[0]`.